# Store the personal data in internal storage

Tags: android

What is the best way to store the pictures which must be private to my application. So that the users cannot open that pictures.

Previously i tried to store in sdcard. but the user can browse and he can delete so it may effect to the application. So can you please suggest the best solution

What if i choose the internal storage of the application ie.,[internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary users cannot get access to internal storage. Users who root their devices can, if they choose to, access internal storage on their devices, including your files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So internal storage can handle 500mb data?

Comment: @user3607798: You cannot assume that you can use 500MB of either internal *or* external storage, as there may not be enough room. There used to be an artificial distinction between the amount of space allocated to internal and external storage, but that is *much* less frequent on Android 3.0+ devices.

Comment: But if i had lots of pictures.I want the pictures must be safe. ie., He can browse but he should not be able to delete the pictures(Specially need for my application).